# can anyone say what is the exact use of await.result(method, duartion.inf) in scala projects?

Tags: scala, asynchronous

**await.result(method, duration.inf)** why we use this? Is there any alternative function for this? In which case we use this mostly? I have seen this in project but i didn't get what is this exactly and why we use this. I have searched this in google but i didn't get clear answer for my question.

Comment: The [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Await$.html) and checking the types of values can help a lot. - Anyways, the TL;DR; is that `method` returned a `Future` _(which represents an asynchronous computation)_ and then they used `Await.result` to wait for it to finish _(making it synchronous again)_ and get the resulting value. - In general, you shouldn't be doing this but rather composing the `Future` using methods like `map` & `flatMap` but maybe there were good reasons for await for the result there

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Luis's comment, `Await.result(???, Duration.Inf)` blocks until the future completes with no timing out.  This blocking introduces the risk of thread starvation (if all threads in an `ExecutionContext` (or equivalent abstraction on a threadpool) are blocked, no tasks (including those which would complete the future) can execute) and is generally to be avoided.

Wherever possible, keep the computation in the asynchronous world using `map`/`flatMap` and friends (or as a last resort, using the callbacks).

Sometimes, however, there are times where you have to cross from the asynchronous world to the synchronous, with the main example being implementing a synchronous API (presumably one over which you have no control) in an internally asynchronous way:

```scala
trait SynchronousAPI {
  // Being synchronous, the implicit contract is "block caller's thread until there's an Int to return"
  def someMethod(x: String): Int
}

class AsynchronousImplementation(implicit val ec: ExecutionContext) extends SynchronousAPI {
  def asyncSomeMethod(x: String): Future[Int] = ???

  def someMethod(x: String): Int =
    // Satisfying the synchronous contract of the API
    Await.result(asyncSomeMethod(x), Duration.Inf)
}
```